# When I Pause a Consumer other Consumer from the same Consumer group should pick up the messages

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am trying to work on a case when there are two or more consumers, listening to one common topic containing only one partition. I am pausing one of the consumers, during this time, other consumers who are not paused , should be able to pick up messages from the topic.
I observe that only when the paused consumer resumes, only then one of the other active consumers can pick up messages.
How can I achieve this through spring kakfka. I am using Spring kafka 2.0.0.M2.

Below is my line of code

```
public class listener{
    @KafkaListener(id = "id2", topics = "abcd", group = "group1", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
        public void listenPartition1(String data, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) List<Integer> partitions, @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) Long offsets, Acknowledgment acknowledgment, Consumer consumer) throws InterruptedException {
            count_consumer2 = count_consumer2 + 1;
            if(count_consumer2 == 10) {
                consumer.pause(consumer.assignment());
            }
            acknowledgment.acknowledge();

    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "id1", topics = "abcd", group = "group1", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
        public void listenPartition1(String data, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) List<Integer> partitions, @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) Long offsets, Acknowledgment acknowledgment, Consumer consumer) throws InterruptedException {
            count_consumer1 = count_consumer1 + 1;
            if(count_consumer1 == 5) {
                consumer.pause(consumer.assignment());
                while(data.database <10){
                      consumer.resume(consumer.assignment());
                 }
            }

             acknowledgment.acknowledge();



        }
}
```

Comment: With pause, you are actually pausing a number of partitions. When a partition is paused no record will be consumed from it until it is resumed again. See https://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#pause(java.util.Collection)

Comment: In your case, what you need to do is to shut down a consumer, then the other one will take care of the partition automatically.

Comment: @amethystic do you know how do I achieve consumer shutdown. I am using consumer.close() but it throws out an error.
Thanks

Comment: What error? Close() should work.

Answer (score 3):

checkout the pause() method docs:

> Suspend fetching from the requested partitions. Future calls to poll(long) will not return any records from these partitions until they have been resumed using resume(Collection).
>
> Note that this method does not affect partition subscription. In particular, it does not cause a group rebalance when automatic assignment is used.

the pause method will not trigger the partition rebalancing, so other consumer in this group will not consume this partition, and Notice that a partition will be consumed by only one consumer in a same consumer group.So in your case, just a consumer works, others are idle.

Comment: Do you have an idea how do I achieve my above-desired use case that if one of my consumer is still processing the message or paused other consumers of the same group can retreive the messages? Closing the consumer is one option but if I have to do this multiple times wouldn't it be an expensive operation?

Comment: @Anand Bangad you can use consumers in different consumer group, if these consumers are in a same group, it can not do this. If you use two consumer which belongs to different group, the two consumer can read message from one partition at the same time.

Comment: I also dont want different consumer groups to read duplicate data. Can synchronization work there?

Comment: I'm afraid it's difficult to do and maybe it does not match the kafka design philosophy. I do not know why you want to do this and maybe you should work around to solve the problem behind this.

Answer (score 0):

You should repartition your topic to have at least as many partitions as you have active mutually exclusive consumers (I.e. same group.id). That's just how Kafka is designed to work.

Comment: I agree. You can also have more consumers than partitions to achieve a certain level of redundancy (if a consumer dies the extra one can pickup the work)